# How to refresh the web page when user select a particular value on dropdown list on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, page-refresh

I'm developing project on rails 2.3.8 and I need to refresh the whole web page when user select particular selection on drop-down menu. How can I do it on rails ?

This is my drop down menu

```
  <%= collection_select("country", "id", @countries , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}, :id => 'xx') %>
  <%= observe_field('xx', :url => { :controller => 'calendar', :action => 'update_country' },:update => 'app_header',:with => "'con=' + escape(value)")%>
```

This finely load the countries so how I can reload the whole page ? please can some one explain me about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a html option to your collection select , onchange => "Javascript code to reload the page"

```
<%= collection_select("country", "id", @countries , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}, :id => 'xx', :onchange => "location.href = '#{root_url}'") %>
```

Comment: Hay thanks for your rply. Can you please explain how to put URL on there. Can I use root_path as url ?

Comment: Hay can call to particular method on controller file and then redirect to different URL ?

Comment: Yes you can do that as well , in place of root_url you can specify your own custom url

Comment: Actually I need to reload the web page after doing the stuff in "update_country" method on 'calendar' controller. How can I do that on controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just refresh the current page:

```
<%= collection_select("country", "id", @countries , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}, :id => 'xx', :onchange => "location.href = window.location.href") %>
```